# How to implement windows8 theme in android/iPhone

Tags: android, iphone, gridview, collections, window

I want to implement windows menu theme in my android and iPhone application.Here I am attaching views of application that have been implemented in one of android application.I thought one way to implement it using grid view in android and using collection view in iPhone.But when it comes to edit mode I am not getting way to implement it.Please give me suggestion how can I go further in it.Any kind of suggestion will be appreciable.
Edit mode contains re-sizing and drag and drop items.

[image: view at first][image: in edit mode]

Things I have tried:I have created grid views dynamically and adding rows dynamically .But I am not getting how to re position the grid items in layout.
Also in iphone I tried to implement this using collection view  but I am not able to change size of specific cell.For edit mode I don't have any idea. Here is the code for displaying grid view.

Xml:

```
<linearlayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:id="@+id/GridItem"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content">

       <imageview android:id="@+id/grid_item"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content">
       </imageview>
    </linearlayout>
```

gridLayout:

```
<gridview xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/GridView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    </gridview>
```

Adapter:
        public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter
        {
        Context context;

```
  public ImageAdapter(Context context)
  {
     context = context;
  }

  @Override
  public int getCount() 
  {
     //return numbers of element u want on the grid
     return 9;
  }

  @Override
  public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
  {
     View v = convertView;

     if ( convertView == null )
     {
        //here we inflat the layout
        LayoutInflater li = getLayoutInflater();
        v = li.inflate(R.layout.grid_item, null);

        //here add the image      
        ImageView iv = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.grid_item_image);
        iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon);
     }

     return v;
  }

  @Override
  public Object getItem(int arg0) {
     // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     return null;
  }

  @Override
  public long getItemId(int arg0) {
     // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     return 0;
  }
  }
```

I have implemeted staggerd gridview to get rows of variable height but not I am not gettign hot to apply drap and drop on them also re positioning on them.

Comment: show your efforts also ??

Comment: @maven hi .. updated the question please look through.

Comment: do post your code? .. if you don't want downvotes

Comment: @maven I have posted code that I have done till now.Please see it